# FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/pic.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android

So I'm taking a picture and after that I'm trying to save it into to that path, but I can't access it. Tried this  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>` and didn't work.

This is how I'm Taking the picture and saving it.

```
private void takePic(View v) 
    {
        // se usa para usar algun app del phone para usar sus cosas para hacer lo que queremos envez de crearlo from scratch
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

        //guarda la imagen
        File imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"pic.jpg");

        imgUri = Uri.fromFile(imgFile);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imgUri);

        //le dice que use el app de camare y le dice que use la camara de atras 1 = la de atras
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }

    //hay que hacerle override para que haga algo que no es parte del metedo.
    //Por ejemplo quiero que guarde la imagen donde yo quiera y no donde tiene por default.
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        //si presiono el buton de ok
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            Uri selectedImg = imgUri;

            // te deja saber que termino de usar la imagen
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImg, null);

            ImageView imgV = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.SteerinRackImgVw);

            // lo mismo de horita
            ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();

            //tiene la data de la img
            Bitmap btMp;

            try 
            {
                btMp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cR, selectedImg);

                imgV.setImageBitmap(btMp);

                //display a small popup de lo que esta pasando
                Toast.makeText(TestMain.this,selectedImg.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 

            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Log.e("error", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Hopefully I didn't miss any brackets :P

When I debug the try and catch block, the program breaks out of the try, on the 1st line.

I hope this makes sense. English isn't my main language. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so nobody knows how to fix it? great...

Comment: Please post your log cat and also try to add permission for read external storage

Comment: ok, will do. When I get my pc back I'll try this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without logcat it is going to be hard to debug, but you could try this for starters

```
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

You have permission to write, but not read. See this for more details [Android Permissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

Comment: Wrong!  
Any app that declares the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is implicitly granted READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: If you see the original question, only android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE was used. That is why I added READ permission as well. RIGHT